# Как взять данные из Intent и установить нужную position в Adapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-intent

Друзья я передаю в `Intent` номер позиции. Как этот `intent` получить в `adapter` и установить переданный `int` номер в `position`?

Если этого не сделать то адаптер открывает всегда сначала 0 элемент массива... А мне нужно открывать тот элемент массива который я передаю `intent` - ом.

Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, код в студию, и как вы передаете номер позиции в Intent, что за адаптер и что за вьюха, вообще не понятно ничего

Comment: К какому виджету этот адаптер подключается? Например` ListView` имеет метод `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`, который устанавливает список в указанную позицию Другие виджеты тоже имеют аналогичные методы. То есть вам вовсе не надо ничего делать с адаптером.

Comment: Всем спасибо я вроде разобрался. С помощью current